# Medium question of SQL level Second Highest Salary

Tags: mysql, sql

//"This question asks in leet code"
//Second Highest Salary

```
select max(salary)  SecondHighestSalary
from Employee
where salary NOT IN (select max(salary) from Employee)
```

Comment: Are you looking for SQL or SQLalchemy answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number() over ( order by salary) and  then use rownum=2 for second heighest sal.

```
select salary SecondHighestSalary from 
(
select row_number() over  ( order by salary desc)  rn, salary
from Employee) subq
where rn=2
```